# Create a list of dictionary keys whose string values are empty, using comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

How would the following be achieved using comprehension so that `bad_keys` only contains the keys where the length of the associated `value` is 0?

```
def _check_data_for_length(self) -> []:
    """
        checks the lengths of the values contained within the dictionary of members
        returns a list of the keys containing data of length 0.
    :return: [] keys of empty values
    """
    bad_keys = []
    for (key, value) in vars(self).items():
        if len(value) == 0:
            bad_keys.append(key)
    return bad_keys
```

Comment: `bad_keys = [key for key, value in vars(self).items() if len(value) == 0]`

Comment: Is the problem that you are getting due to some objects not having a length, i.e., if they are just numbers?

Comment: If so, you could just put a `try... except...` around the `if len(value) == 0: bad_keys.append(key)`

Comment: if `value` has a `len()` you can typically simplify to `bad_keys = [key for key, value in vars(self).items() if value]`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp correcting your syntax, adding brackets giving --  `bad_keys = [key for (key, value) in vars(self).items() if len(value) == 0]` does return what I'm expecting. Appreciated.

Comment: The original syntax was already correct…

Comment: thanks @deceze now I'm confused it now seems to work either with or without the brackets thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: whoever marked this question down, please explain how it is not adding value to stack overflow?

Comment: Have you attempted to write this as a comprehension and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I was putting the if clause prior to the for, having viewed something on YouTube, big mistake.

Comment: Then the better question would have been to post that attempt and clarify the problem with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to return the bad keys of things that have a length, then you could do (edited based on the comment by @deceze):

```py
x = {"a": 1, "b": [3., 4.], "c": []}

badkeys = [k for k, v in x.items() if hasattr(v, '__len__') and len(v) == 0]
```

which gives:

```
['c']
```

Comment: `[k for k, v in x.items() if hasattr(v, '__len__') and len(v) == 0]`…?!

Comment: Yes, that's more succinct. I'll edit it. I wasn't sure about the precedence of things in conditions and where `len(v)` would get called even if the `hasattr(v, '__len__')` was False.

Comment: `and` operator short-circuiting still works the same as elsewhere.